# Does Validator.SetFocusOnError work without a postback?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an ASP.net page with a RegexValidator.  The RegexValidator successfully displays my validation error text when a user types a value out of range and navigates (tabs) off of the control.  At that point, it doesn't set the focus to that control, even though I have SetFocusOnError="true".

The focus does appear to be set when I click a button on that page.

Is focus supposed to be set as soon as the javascript detects on issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is your RegEx validator inside of a naming container? If so, you'll need to do a little hacking.

Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2007/06/29/a-quick-fix-for-the-validator-setfocusonerror-bug.aspx) for some assistance and for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The focus will return to the control when you attempt to submit the form. By default EnableClientScript is enabled, which performs client-side validation so no, there won't be a postback if validation fails and the browser is able to perform client-side validation.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx):

> Use the EnableClientScript  property
>   to specify whether client-side
>   validation is enabled.
>
> Validation controls always perform
>   validation on the server. They also
>   have complete client-side
>   implementation that allows
>   DHTML-supported browsers (such as
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0 and
>   later) to perform validation on the
>   client. Client-side validation
>   enhances the validation process by
>   checking user input before it is sent
>   to the server. This allows errors to
>   be detected on the client before the
>   form is submitted, avoiding the round
>   trip of information necessary for
>   server-side validation.
>
> By default, this value is set to true,
>   which enables client-side validation
>   if the browser supports it.

If you want immediate feedback from the validation control when the user tabs off of it, you can set its `ErrorMessage` property and set its `Display` property to either `Dynamic` or `Static`.